# Key exists error while using ADD into Couchbase

Tags: node.js, nosql, couchbase

I'm using Couchbase NoSQL DB but I guess this can happen with any NoSQL DB. Here's what happens:

I'm checking if a specific key exists and I'm catching the keyNotFound error to now ADD this key into the database. See the code:

```
// retrieve the document for this connection_id
db.get(connection_id, function(err, result) {
if (err && err.code === 13) {   
// Catched a keyNotFound -> define a new document for the voice connection
var voice_c = {
        voice_count: '1',
            voice_duration: call_duration,
    last_contact: call_start
};
// Add this new Voice_c document for this connection_id to DB
db.add(connection_id, voice_c, function(err, result) {
        if (err)
        throw err; // whilst adding a new voice connection
});
```

When I get to the db.add step I get an error "Key exists (with a different CAS value)" even though I just checked fragments of a millisecond before if the same key exist (and it didn't exist).

I couldn't replicate the error at the same place in my data feed but the second time it happened even earlier, indicating it's a random event. I'm puzzled as to how this can happen unless there's a big bug in my code which I just don't see.

There is no other code running and altering the documents in the NoSQL DB, it all runs locally on my MBP. The DB was flushed and was empty before I started to run my script.

I've checked manually in the data feed and when it happened the first time there was indeed the same connection_id about 50 records earlier. But in the second instance the error was thrown when the connection_id was showing up the first time (though it comes up some 19000 records later). Very strange, hope someone can help me how I can avoid getting this error.

Comment: Have you tried to use just `add` without `get`? Get in this situation is useless because `add` will not store doc in db if it exists.

Comment: @m03geek I left out the code for the part where the key is being found (which is happening most of the time) and where I do update the numbers in the document. So the GET isn't useless in that case though I agree with you for the view of that code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the "stale:false" option of couchbase for renewing the index? i also would recommend using async.waterfall for both statements, it increases readability and decreases callback hell.